# PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP during creation of cmake files

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

The FindProtobuf module available in cmake offers the command PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP that calls protoc from within cmake. This command is normally executed at compilation time (when you run "make"). Since some of my source files include the generated files, the dependency check during "cmake .." fails because the files are not yet generated.

Is it possible to have this command run at configuration time right before the dependency check?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the FindProtobuf.cmake file, it looks like `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` should make those files when you call the function at configuration time.  When it does this it should print `Running C++ protocol buffer compiler on ${MATCH_PATH} with root ${PROTOROOT}, generating: ${CPP_FILE}`  Do you see that when you configure?

Comment: If by configure you mean the execution of the "cmake .." command, no. I see that when I compile the code with make.

Comment: Take a look at [ADD_DEPENDENCIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_dependencies).  Try running `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` with `DEBUG` and look at the information it gives.  You might be able to tell your target to be dependent on the output of `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` so that it figures out what to do at build time (i.e. when you run `make`).

Comment: BTW, I was wrong before.  It does actually create the files at build time, not at configure time (i.e. running `cmake`).  Sorry about that.

Comment: One more thing.  It *is* possible to make this run at configure time, but it will require you modifying the FindProtobuf.cmake file and including it with your source.

Comment: Moving the configuration time is just hacking around the original error. Usually the dependency checking of CMake should automatically find out that your code depends on files to be generated by that macro. Common causes for a broken dependency tracking are weird preprocessor macros obfuscating the #include commands or missing INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES directives inside CMake so that CMake actually cannot know that things belong together.

Answer (score 4):

You can mark the files as going to be generated, so that the dependency check will work:

```
file(GLOB PROTOBUF_FILELIST ${PROTO_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.proto)
foreach( proto_file ${PROTOBUF_FILELIST} )
   get_filename_component(proto_name ${proto_file} NAME_WE)
   get_filename_component(proto_path ${PROTO_INCLUDE_DIR} ABSOLUTE)
   set_source_files_properties("${proto_path}/${proto_name}.pb.cc"
                               "${proto_path}/${proto_name}.pb.h"
                               PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
endforeach()
```